# Why does this report "Object is possibly undefined" despite type guard?

Tags: typescript

```js
interface A {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c?: string;
}

function f(a: A) {
    for (const key of ['a', 'b', 'c'] as ['a', 'b', 'c']) {
        if (a[key] === undefined) continue;

        console.log(a[key].length);
    }
}
```

The compiler reports `a[key] is possibly undefined`.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzAbhzwCMjTyRrbcEB+RsymgXyxYYAVxAIwwAPYhkMABSE0ASkxtZkqMjkJppZAGsIAT2SSYyANoByOFYA0yK3XuOEVgLr5ilmy6d+3dxVsPFDkYHMFC0MjTwBeBORRABMIGFAIZJUdcFBhCBo1UJziSQAbCAA6MskKKJj3aogWMAALJRpQgT4gA)

I'm checking in advance, `if (a[key] === undefined) continue;`.

Why?

Comment: Because that conditional isn't narrowing anything, it's not really a type guard. `key` is still `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, so (as far as the compiler's concerned) `a[key]` could still be the optional property that might be `undefined`. If you extracted the value `a[key]` to e.g. `const value = a[key];` and tested *that*, it would get narrowed.

Comment: Thank you for helpful explanation! You solved my issue.